# Select users and order them by their article total views

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an article table that stores the user id, article id and the article views. I want to get all the users from this table and order them by their total article views (sum).

See the table below.

```
id | user_id | article_id | views
1      2          1          34
2      2          2          6
3      3          3          39
4      3          4          20
```

I want to get something like this.

```
user_id | views
 3          59
 2          40
```

I can get the views of one user by using `SELECT sum(views) FROM articles where user_id = 2` , but I want to get all the users and order them by their total views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `group by` clause and an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(views) AS sum_of_views
FROM articles
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY SUM(views) DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = "SELECT sum(views) FROM articles WHERE user_id = 2 ORDER BY views DESC";
```

Comment: the OP wants all the users so WHERE clause with user_id is wrong in this case

Comment: Also, why introduce PHP or whatever that is in the answer when the question says nothing about anything else but SQL?